# How to say: I only speak spanish

Tags: sentence, translation, spanish

Are these sentences correct?

- I only speak spanish.
- I speak spanish alone.
- I just speak spanish.

Are there other ways to say the same thing?

Comment: All of them are correct.  The first and third are more usual, of which the first is the less ambiguous.

Comment: Sólo hablo español

Comment: @MattЭллен I was looking for english sentences

Comment: @user61979 Not sure I agree that the second one means the same thing. 'I speak Spanish alone, but English with my girlfriend'.

Comment: @WS2 That depends on whether you parse *alone* as an adjective or an adverb.

Comment: "I speak Spanish alone" is grammatical but reading it without intonation I take it to mean something like "When I am alone, I speak Spanish to myself".

Comment: None of the statements is correct. The writer clearly also has some competence in English.

Comment: To answer your question about alternative formulations, you could also say "I solely speak Spanish" (or "I speak solely Spanish"), "All I [can] speak is Spanish" (or "Spanish is all I [can] speak"), "I can't speak anything but Spanish", and "The only language I [can] speak is Spanish" (or "Spanish is the only language I [can] speak"). -- Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other sentence I can think of that maintains the clarity of the first sentence would be **"I speak only Spanish"** — this is just a transposition of word order.

Also, it depends on what exactly you are trying to say as these sentences do not mean the same thing (just as others suggest):

- **"I only speak Spanish.**" -This infers that you will only speak in the Spanish language. This sounds pretty straightforward to me.
- **"I speak Spanish alone."** -This sentence *is* ambiguous; it reads as if you will only speak in Spanish by yourself or that you are the only person who speaks Spanish among a group of people. The former doesn't mean the same as the first sentence; the latter wouldn't make sense because no one else is mentioned in the sentence to justify the use of the word "alone".
- **"I just speak Spanish."** -A colloquial version of the first sentence, it also infers that Spanish is the only language you can (or will) speak. Also, it may infer that you speak this language *specifically* among other languages.

(:

-MP

Comment: Couldn't you parse 'alone' as an adverb rather than as an adjective?

Comment: In the above example, it is being used as an adverb, is it not? When reading "I speak Spanish alone", (and considering the context you are presenting) it's hard to say whether "alone" modifies "speak" or "I", but in the sentence "I'm alone", "alone" modifies the subject without a doubt. So the ambiguity still remains if you choose to write "I speak Spanish alone". That being said, I'm not sure that the word "alone" will provide you with the clarity you need. To me, it looks like a matter of word choice. (Also, I don't like adverbs.) (: